# Pytorch loading saved weights but not working

Tags: computer-vision, pytorch

I have this code. I save weights after every epoch and the code saves it. But when I load the weights the loss value starts from the initial loss value which means the loading is failing somehow.

```
net = torchvision.models.resnet18(pretrained=True)
num_ftrs = net.fc.in_features
net.fc = nn.Linear(num_ftrs, 136)

def train():
    device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
    criterion = L1Loss(reduction='sum')

    lr = 0.0000001
    optimizer = optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=lr, weight_decay=0.0005)

    net.to(device)

    state = torch.load('face2.txt')
    net.load_state_dict(state['state_dict'])
    optimizer.load_state_dict(state['optimizer'])

    for epoch in range(int(0), 200000):
        for batch, data in enumerate(trainloader, 0):
            torch.cuda.empty_cache()

            inputs, labels = data
            inputs, labels = inputs.to(device), labels.to(device)

            optimizer.zero_grad()

            outputs = net(inputs).reshape(-1, 68, 2)
            loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
            running_loss += loss.item()

        state = {
            'epoch': epoch,
            'state_dict': net.state_dict(),
            'optimizer': optimizer.state_dict(),
        }

        torch.save(state, 'face2.txt')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    train()
```

The initial loss is 50k plus and after some thousand epochs the loss becomes 50-60. Now when I re-run the code I expect it to start from a near loss value but it starts from  around 50k again.

Comment: Generally, models are saved in the `.pt` or `.pth` format, not the `.txt` format. Could you try using that? Also, check this [link](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html) where the code for saving and loading models is given.

Comment: I have used .pt as well.. Didnt make any difference though

Answer (score 0):

The code you wrote:

```
net = torchvision.models.resnet18(pretrained=True)
```

means you start over again with the same net - pretrained resnet18. Instead, you should load the last state if present, this would fix your problem.

I will slightly update your notation:

```
state = {
    'epoch': epoch,
    'model_state_dict': net.state_dict(),
    'optimizer_state_dict': optimizer.state_dict(),
    ...
}
torch.save(state, filepath)
```

Learnable parameters are the first state_dict (model state dict).

The second state_dict is the optimizer state dict. You recall that the optimizer is used to improve our learnable parameters. But the optimizer state_dict is fixed. Nothing to learn in there.

Your code at some point should look like:

```
model.load_state_dict(state['model_state_dict'])
optimizer.load_state_dict(state['optimizer_state_dict'])
```